# Overlay covering up a JQuery UI 1.8.2 dialog

Tags: jquery-ui

I am using a jQuery UI modal dialog on a JSF page that also has primefaces components inside the dialog div.  When I set the modal property to true the overlay covers up the dialog content as well.  Here is my dialog definition:

```
if (jQuery("#rangeChoice").val() == 'Custom') {       
  jQuery("#rangeDialog").dialog({
    modal: true,
    draggable: false,
    minHeight: 375, minWidth: 450,
    resizable: false,
    title: 'Create Custom Date Range',
    closeOnEscape: false,
    open: function(event, ui) { jQuery(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide(); }
  });
return;
}
```

and my content for the div:

```
<div id="rangeDialog" style="display: none;">
<div class="customRangeButtons" style="z-index: 4999;">
    <!-- Clipped for brevity, the buttons alone are covered by the overlay -->
    <span>
        <p:commandButton value="Cancel" actionListener="#{bean.cancelCDR}" update="pGraphs"/>
    </span>
    <span style="margin-left: 300px;">
        <p:commandButton  value="Submit" type="submit" action="#{bean.saveCDR()}" update="pGraphs"/>
    </span>
</div>
```

I am using Primefaces 2.2.1, and I have a feeling related to who is controlling the overlay div.  I did try adding my own overlay div in the page and showing it in the open event of a non modal dialog.  It also covered the dialog for z-index values > 3.  Values 1 and 2 were okay though some other controls on the page were above that.  Note this is a workaround to using a p:dialog as it was causing my actionListeners not to fire.

What else can I try?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the z-index on the div tag is being overridden by the `.dialog` itself.  The `.dialog`'s default z-index is 1000.  You can change this when you create the dialog by changing the `zIndex` option like so:

```
jQuery("#rangeDialog").dialog({
    modal: true,
    draggable: false,
    minHeight: 375, minWidth: 450,
    resizable: false,
    title: 'Create Custom Date Range',
    closeOnEscape: false,
    open: function(event, ui) { jQuery(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide(); },
    zIndex: 4999
  });
```

See the options tab in the documentation for more info:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Comment: I added the zIndex option and I get the same result.  I went ahead and tried zIndex: 32000 and it still was behind the overlay.  A zIndex of -1 made the overlay not appear at all.

Comment: Did you also remove the style tag on your div?

Comment: I had not.  Removed the style now, and I get the same result.

Comment: Is the dialog supposed to open on page load or is there an event that you're using to bring it up?

Comment: The dialog is opened on a onChange event from a select box when the 'Custom' option is selected, via putting the .dialog call inside the if statement above.

Comment: Ah, I found that several parents up from my div some css that set the z-index to 2.  Removing that fixed the issue.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: It's always the little things  :)  Glad I could help!