# jQuery UI dialog disabled and unclickable behind layer

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a jquery UI dialog on my page thusly:

[image]

```
$(function() {
    $("#dialogDone").dialog({
        closeOnEscape: true,
        modal: true,
        width: 350,
        autoResize:true,
        show: "drop",
        hide: "drop",
        autoOpen: false
    });
});

<div id="dialogDone" title="Activity Done?" class="RNDDialog">
    <div style="text-align: left;">
        You are about to stamp this activity as DONE. Notifications may be sent out, and only Project Admins can reverse this.
        <br><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="chkKeepShowingDoneWarning" class="RNDCheckbox" checked>Keep showing me this
    </div>

    <br><br>

    <center>
    <button class="GreenButton" onclick="stampActivityDone()">Yes, it is DONE</button>
    <button class="GrayButton" style="margin-left: 10px" onclick="cancelDone()">Cancel</button>
    </center>
</div>
```

After launching the dialog, nothing inside it is clickable. The grayish layer that normally covers the whole screen (but not the dialog normally) and makes everything in the background disabled, is also for some reason covering the dialog itself. I cannot click either button, nor check/uncheck the checkbox.

[image]

[You can see it for yourself here](https://www.rightnowdone.com/_test.html).

I created the test page in the link above as a bare-bones reproducible minimal example. I have used jquery dialogs many times in this web app and others, but for some reason on this particular page, I get this strange behavior and cannot figure it out.

After launching the dialog, even though everything on the page including the dialog contents is disabled, you can still hit ESC, which dismisses the dialog and makes the page accessible again. This tells me that the fundamental jquery UI dialog wiring and event model is still working.

I read [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947823/overlay-covering-up-a-jquery-ui-1-8-2-dialog) that suggested setting the z-index of the dialog, so I experimented with that but it did nothing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I ran an HTML formatter on your test page source code and it looks like you have a lot of unclosed tags. Some of those unclosed tags are likely causing elements to have parents that you don't expect. I would recommend very carefully reading your code and making sure that every opening tag has a matching closing tag at the position you expect.

Comment: I ran the same thing, and the only unclosed tags it showed me were `<br>` tags, which of course aren't really unclosed, and those don't cause any problems. Can you please give me one example of an unclosed tag? Or at least a link to the service you used to do the scan?

Comment: I had 1 unclosed <center> tag which I removed and it made no difference. After that change, I ran the HTML through 2 different services, and it said no unclosed tags: https://www.aliciaramirez.com/closing-tags-checker/ and http://jonaquino.blogspot.com/2013/05/unclosed-tag-finder.html

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I was referencing an older jquery UI css file (1.9.1) instead of the newer one that goes with jquery 1.12.1. This is an edge case admittedly, but maybe it will help someone in the future who references an incorrect jquery UI css file.